# How to simply copy a docker container from one server onto another server?

Tags: database, docker

Simple question that I have not be able to find a straight answer on. I have a database that I've dockerized inside an ec2, this database has a lot of production data. I've been trying to find a way to simply make back-up copies of this database from time to time if in case the worst happens. So as a precaution I am looking for ways to routinely copy the docker container itself and then place that into another container, is this possible? I'd also like the ability to move it from the EC2 into another EC2 or onto my desktop.

Are these things possible with docker?

Thank you

Comment: I really, really, REALLY hope that your data isn't inside the container. Because if it is, then your data is gone when/if the container or the machine restarts.

Comment: I'd use normal database backup tools here, and not particularly worry about it being in a container.  The container is (mostly) a wrapper around the database process, and you don't need to duplicate the process.  The data should be in an external volume of some sort (or else you will lose the data sooner or later) and commands that operate on the container filesystem tend to ignore volume data.

Comment: @HansKilian I mounted the data to a volume outside the container. Is it considered bad practice to store prod data inside a container? I am new to this. This is for Neo4j Graph Data, I spun up a graph database inside the ec2 with docker and this is basically where I host the data at.

Comment: @DavidMaze what backup tools would you recommend here? pretty new to containers/docker in general.

Comment: @Preston_Jarvis If your data is on a volume, then they're outside the container and you're fine. Like David Maze, I'd also use the database tools that come with the database to back up data, rather than backing up the docker volume data.

Comment: @HansKilian What tools can do this? is it bad practice to host a prod db on a container? I want thinking of making container copies using ```docker save > scp to other machine > docker load > docker run```

Comment: Use the exact same tools you'd use without Docker; run the exact same migration process you'd use to move a non-container database from one host to another.  This is not a programming-related question, and depending on your needs, another site like [devops.se], [sf], or [dba.se] might be a more appropriate place to ask.

Comment: @DavidMaze I've never done a migration process, especially with a graph-based one. Any suggested I'd be grateful or resource. Thanks. My understanding now is not to use a container for a database...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, but `docker export` might be the thing you're looking for: https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/container/export/

As per the documentation, on the old server, you would run:

```bash
docker export red_panda > latest.tar
```

And then on the new server you would run:

```bash
docker export --output="latest.tar" red_panda
```

However, I'm not sure this will acomplish your data-recovery goals - a better option would be to set up [docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) and just copy that data directories themselves.  Additionally, I'd recommend using the native database backup tools that are provided with nearly all databases.

Comment: For most database containers, `docker export` will not include the database data.

Comment: @DavidMaze I found this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-move-docker-containers-between-different-hosts Couldn't I simply ```docker save > scp to other machine > docker load > docker run```?

Comment: `docker save` only includes the original images; the packaged database server itself, not a running copy of the database and not the per-instance data.